# Why cant I access this dynamic property from deserialized Newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am sending an object from one microservice to another so have serialized an object that contains this property

```
public class Template 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileFormat { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to model a `TemplateDTO` in the other microservice that gets this message as I only need to access one of the Template properties. Also, I do need the `Id` later on when sending this to a different microservice that's why I need it otherwise I could just send a single string prop. This is the property in my DTO:

```
public dynamic Template { get; set; }
```

The deserialization works but I can't seem to

```
templateObj.FileFormat;   //templateObj is equal to reportJson.Template
```

This is what the object looks like in debug:

[image]

I get this error when trying to access anything from the object:

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'FileFormat' and no accessible extension method 'FileFormat' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing here?

EDIT

The serialized object has multiple properties and one of them is Template. When I deserialize it in another microservice:

```
var reportJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportDTO>(serializedMessage);
```

I get the above issues.

The ReportDTO looks like this:

```
public class ReportDTO
{
    public dynamic Template { get; set; }

    ... 
}
```

Comment: You need to share more code. You have class named Template. But then you have a dynamic property. Where this property is declared? How are you doing JSON deserialization? What is the data type of `templateObj` ? Can you also share the sample JSON which you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the `templateObj` is just the dynamic object after deserializing the message. The class for `Template` is in Microservice A and the dynamic property is in the `ReportDTO` for Microservice B.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. What happens whey you try to access `reportJson.Template.FileFormat`?

Comment: This is the error I get from that. The `templateObj` is equal to `reportJson.Template`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out when I deserialize it through

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedObj);
```

Since the Template is dynamic it gets converted into a `JObject` automatically so I have to use something like this to get the value:

```
(string)((JObject)templateObj)["FileFormat"]
```

> Output: "PDF"

Answer (score 1):

Given you have these classes:

```
public class Report
{
    public Template Template { get; set; }
}

public class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileFormat { get; set; }
}

public class ReportDto
{
    public dynamic Template { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should serialize and deserialize like this:

```
        var report = new Report
        {
            Template = new Template { Id = 5, FileFormat = "PDF" }
        };
        var serializedReport = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(report);

        var deserializedReport = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReportDto>(serializedReport);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedReport.Template.FileFormat); // Output : PDF
```

Your mistake is you use deserializedReport.FileFormat instead of deserializedReport.Template.FileFormat

Comment: Sorry, should have been more detailed. The serialized object doesn't only contain the Template. There are more properties and one of the properties is a Template. I do want to use a static DTO for the whole message, just not for Template.

Comment: The templateObj in my question was already equal to deserializedReport.Template

Comment: It's all in the question. I have put the deserialization in there. The only extra bit is `templateObj = reportsJson.Template`